# Extjs 3.4 custom JSONReader

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I haven't had a question from quite a while, but I finally ended up hitting a wall here. Anyways, to make this easy. I am trying to create a JSON store in extjs 3.4 (work related, and no I am not updating).
Well, I created the queries as usual with the proper response and fill it up. My problem is that I have 1 extra property on the JSON that I want to be able to pull and use on the app.
Sample of my JSON from the response object in chrome:

```
myInventory: [{Priority:1, PMNumber:444, Description:fix-a-tape, Assets:3, Storage_Count:0,…},…]
percent: 97.040498442368
totalCount: "3"
```

Now, I know this is correctly formatted because the Grid I am using gets populated, but I can't get the percent property. So my question is, how do you pull an extra parameter on the datastore building block of code when you have one extra parameter that is not usual on EXTjs, in my case the percent?
I tried doing a metachange on the JSONReader, but all I get is percent:"percent" on the properties as I inspect the datastore after it's creation.

Comment: I know I can do another query, and then a separate datastore, but I think that is a waste. I should be able to add a parameter to the store to be used say in a grid, or in another element that uses dynamic data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.data.JsonReader has a property [jsonData](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonReader-property-jsonData) which is exactly what you need. A quick example:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: 'data/test.json',
        root: 'dataRoot',
        fields: ['fieldA', 'fieldB'],
        idProperty: 'id',
        storeId: 'myStore'
    });

    store.on('load', function(store) {
        console.log(store.reader.jsonData.someOtherProperty);
    });

    store.load(); 

});
```

and the data/test.json looks like this:

```
{
    dataRoot: [{
        id: 0,
        fieldA: 'a',
        fieldB: 'b' 
    }],
    someOtherProperty: 'abc'
}
```

There could also be an alternative approach that you manually (not via store.load()) perform Ext.Ajax request, use the properties you need and then manually call [Ext.data.JsonStore.loadData()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-loadData) using the data you got from Ajax request.

Comment: I already tried this. I can see the data from the JSON coming over and correctly formatted, but still there is no availability of the "otherProperty". I been messing around with the metadata property for the JSON and I somewhat got it to work, but it is not the answer yet as I am not getting anything displayed on the grid ATM. Thanks for the pointer, even though I already got to the same idea 5 days ago.